# Garbled Comment Text

Tags: discussion, comments

Okay, I was confused the [first time](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29636/who-really-killed-derek/29637#29637) I saw it.

> Ah, so here's what really happened, then: Gubznf, orvat hanoyr gb
>   cresbez uvf wbo qhr gb qvfgnapr, fgnegrq gb unir zbarl vffhrf. Ur tbg
>   va, onq, jvgu n ybna funex. Uvf ebbzzngrf, orvat boyvivbhf gb gur snpg
>   gung ur pbhyqa'g jbex fb sne njnl, qvqa'g abgvpr. Ur orpnzr qrcerffrq
>   naq wbvarq n perj, eboovat onaxf. Bar qnl, gurl eboorq n onax npebff
>   sebz Qrerx'f pbssrr fubc naq ur jvgarffrq vg. Gubznf'f perj pbreprq
>   uvz vagb xvyyvat Qrerx gb cerirag uvz sebz grfgvslvat

And now I've seen it a [second time](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30112/can-you-see-me/30113#30113)

> It's not in bar bs vgf fvtaf

I'm pretty sure this is cipher text but I can't find anything about it or what cipher it uses. Help me out?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Common courtesy when you can't spoiler things easily is to use rot13, a cipher that shifts every letter forward 13 places: A and N switch, B and O switch, C and P switch... all the way up to M and Z.

[Here](http://rot13.com) is a site that will automatically encode or decode for you.

Comment: This worries me. Scrambled comments provide literally no constructive value to anyone who's not in on this, excluding almost all people from discussion - particularly new users to the site, who won't have any clue what's going on.

Comment: @Emrakul: I agree, which is why I always add "(rot13)" and link to rot13.com in the very rare case when I need to add a spoiler in a comment.

Comment: If this is really something people find necessary, maybe we should consider making linking to rot13 a global policy, then... otherwise, these comments are just going to harm usability for everyone (even more than they do already).

Comment: Common courtesy is not to require people to install an add-on to the browser to read your comments.  rot12(Eqq tai mzzakuzs uf ue?)